# Unexpected character at the beginning of file when wrote using blob in javascript

Tags: javascript, matlab, character, blob

I was using blob to write a file with javascript in the client side.
Following is the code snippet I used:

```
var blob = new Blob(['hello'], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "path.m");
```

Unfortunately, there is a junk character at the beginning of the file as flagged by Matlab:

[image]

I don't know what this character is and how Blob is introducing them. But I need to fix it before I can generate an actual matlab .m file.

I request anybody who knows how to fix this to help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It's likely a BOM (byte order mark).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom#2223926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. I changed the character set from utf-8 to ISO-8859-1 as follows:

```
var blob = new Blob(['hello'], {type: "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1"});
```

and it solved the problem.